# Bluetooth device is detected as a Low Energy and an ordinary Bluetooth device with the same MAC address and name

Tags: c#, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm creating a Windows utility to connect to Bluetooth devices. I'm using [Windows.Devices.Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.Enumeration?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=winrt-19041) API. I have noticed that some bluetooth devices (in particular Samsung smart TVs) are detected by Windows as 2 devices: LE bluetooth device and ordinary bluetooth device. But MAC and name of these 2 devices are the same.

To which device (LE or non LE) user should be connected in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth LE devices (v4 and up) are usually backwards compatible. That being said, the two types of Bluetooth, classic (< v4) and LE (> v4), are completely different from one another.

Bluetooth Classic works with a classic master-slave connection, where one device sends instructions to the other, and the other obeys.

Bluetooth Low Energy changes this completely and replaces the architecture with a client-server focused architecture. Devices subscribe to the idea of GATT connections, they have specific rules and functions decided by Services and Characteristics. You get the Service channel of a device, hook onto a specific Characteristic and read/write/subscribe to notifications coming from it. This new connection type allows the peripheral device to act only when it is being called on, thus reducing the need for a constant connection polling on the server side and saving energy. It also allows you to connect to multiple BLE devices at once.

I recommend that you use Bluetooth Low Energy with all your connections moving forward. It is more energy-efficient, the connection is generally more stable, and the range of BLE is also greater. Bluetooth Low Energy aims to be backwards compatible, so your app should also be compatible with the newest version of BLE (v5+)